# Filtering data in table1 on sheet1 and copying specific columns into table2 on sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA. I have a table1 on sheet1, I need to filter rows of table1 based on one of the columns of table1 using a string. Then from the filtered rows I need to copy the data from specific columns and paste/insert the data under the same header names in table2 located in sheet2. I'm looking to update sheet2 constantly as changes are made in sheet1 as the table doesn't have a fixed number of rows.

This is the table I'm working with
[Food and Electronics Stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oICoD.png)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
Sub UpdateTable()

Dim myTable1 As ListObject
Dim myArray1 As Variant
Dim myTable2 As ListObject


Set myTable1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
Set myArray1 = myTable.ListColumns(3).Range
Set myTable2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("table2")
'Need to include other variables

For Each cell In myArray1
    If cell.Value = "FOOD" Then 'copy paste data under Item, Quantity and Cost into table2 located in sheet2
        
Next cell

End Sub
```

**Edit: Modified Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTable()

With Sheets("foodSheet").ListObjects("tableFood")
    'Check If any data exists in the table
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        'Clear Content from the table
        .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    End If
End With

'Delete empty rows and shift cells up
Dim i As Long
With Sheets("foodSheet").ListObjects("tableFood").DataBodyRange
    For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next
End With

Dim col, r As Long, rng As Range
 ' apply filter
With Sheet1.ListObjects("tableStock").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="FOOD"
    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With

' check number of rows visible
If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Or rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
    With Sheet2.ListObjects("tableFood")
        ' count existing rows in table 2
        If .InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
            r = .Range.Rows.Count
        Else
            r = 1
        End If
    End With
    For Each col In Array("[Item]", "[Quantity]", "[Cost]")
        Sheet1.Range("tableStock" & col).Copy Sheet2.Range("tableFood" & col).Rows(r)
    'Need to shift cells of table down when pasting in the data
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTable2()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheet1 ' Sheets("tablestock") ?
    Set ws2 = Sheets("foodSheet")
 
    ' Clear Content from the table
    With ws2.ListObjects("tableFood")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
        End If
    End With

    Dim a, col, rng As Range, r As Long, n As Long
     ' apply filter
    With ws1.ListObjects("tableStock").Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="FOOD"
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    
    ' count visible rows
    For Each a In rng.Areas
        r = r + a.Rows.Count
    Next

    ' check for data
    If r > 1 Then
       ' expand table2 space
        With ws2.ListObjects("tableFood")
            If r > 2 Then
                .Range.Offset(2).Resize(r - 2).EntireRow.Insert
                .Resize .Range.Resize(r)
            End If
        End With

        ' copy data
        For Each col In Array("[Item]", "[Quantity]", "[Cost]")
            ws1.Range("tableStock" & col).Copy ws2.Range("tableFood" & col)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified this for what I need (Updated Question). I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I have to clear the data in table2 because otherwise the data just gets copied underneath it every time new items are added to table1 and the code is run. Then, after clearing there are still blank rows, so those get removed then the cells shift up and the updated data is copied in. I have another table3 right underneath table2 so when the data gets copied to table2 it overwrites the data in table3, so I'm not sure how to integrate shifting cells down so it doesn't overwrite table3.

Comment: @Don So you want table2 cleared before entering the filtered records from table1 ?

Comment: @Don I have updated my code. It there one blank line between table2 and table 3 ?

Comment: No space between table2 and table3. The update2 works and the comments really help understand how it works, thanks.

Comment: How would you account for a row of merged cells between each table (table1, a row of merged cells, then table2)? I ended up changing the format of my sheet and I'm getting errors at "ws1.Range("tableStock" & col).Copy ws2.Range("tableFood" & col)"

Comment: @Don Do you mean Table2 and 3 ?. Are the tables and the merged cells the same width ? Easiest way would be to unmerge, copy and then merge ,

Comment: Yes, Table1, Table2, and Table 3 etc. My plan was to make the code into a function by passing arguments so I can call on the function to update as many tables as I'd like with specific filter words and information. The merged cells are the same width as the table and just have the title of the table as strings. The merged cells are not part of the table above or below, they are just there to make it easy for readers to identify the tables.

Comment: @Don Is table1,2,3 on same sheet now ? I don't get an error with merged row between tables provided the tables are the same width.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same sheet. I tried it on a new excel workbook and the code works with a merged row between tables. I think it was the way I was formatting my current workbook. Thanks for the checking and clarifying.